# Got 'stack smashing detected' after counting words in file (using C)

Tags: c, scanf, stack-smash

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 200

int main() {

    FILE *input = fopen("word_list_final.txt", "r");
    char buffer[SIZE];
    int counter = 0;

    if (input == NULL) {
        printf("Error! Could not open file\n"); 
        exit(-1);
    }

    while (fscanf(input, "%s\n", buffer) != EOF) {
        counter++;
    }

    fclose(input);
    printf("%d\n", counter);
    return 0;
}
```

After executing, program prints correct result and mentioned message. (File, I'm reading from, contains one word per line)

Outputs:

> 89937042
> *** stack smashing detected ***: terminated
> Aborted (core dumped)

How to get rid of error message?

Comment: Does the bug disappear if you change `while (fscanf(input, "%s\n", buffer) != EOF) {` to `while ( fscanf(input, "%199s", buffer) == 1 ) {` ?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally include a [mre]. Your code itself seems to fulfill this criteria, but you have not provided a sample input file that reproduces the bug.

Comment: My only explanation for this bug is that you are overflowing `buffer`, which would only happen if you have a word longer than 199 characters. I am unable to reproduce this bug when I create my own input file, and you have not yet provided any input file which claims to reproduce the bug.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel now bug disappeared, but I got result 89937045, 3 words more then file contains, and a do not have any word longer then 199 chatacters

Comment: Please include the 2-3 longest lines in `word_list_final.txt` in the question

Comment: Between the line containing the `fscanf` and `counter++`, I suggest that you add the following line (inside the `while` loop): `if ( strlen(buffer) > 198 ) {printf( "input too long\n" ); exit( EXIT_FAILURE );}` You will have to add `#include <string.h>` for this to work. When you run your program afterwards, do you get the error message `"input too long"`?

Comment: Thanks for your help, actually there were words longer than 200 characters. I apologize for my self-confidence.

Comment: @LukaIllich: Then that is probably the reason why you count 3 more words than are actually in the file. Since `scanf` can only match 199 characters at once, you will need two or more loop iterations to handle a word with more than 199 characters.

Comment: `fscanf` does not return `EOF`. Use: `== 1` in the `while`

Comment: @CraigEstey: `fscanf` can return `EOF`. However, you are right that `== 1` is better, because it can also return `0`.

Comment: Even if you have now solved your problem, if you want to prevent your question from being closed, you may still want to provide a sample input file which reproduces the problem. That way, your question would also have a higher chance of being upvoted.

Comment: The `'\n'` in `"%s\n"` is superfluous. Get rid of it.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your input file contains a line of 200 characters or more, so when `fscanf` places the bytes in `buffer`, there is an overflow, which overwrites whatever is on your stack after the `buffer` array.